# Joining two 2020 aluminium profiles to make a 2040profile

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I recently bought a 2020 profile and after I got the product I realised that I needed a 2040 profile instead.

So, I was thinking of buying one more 2020 profile and connecting it with the 2020 profile parallel to each other to make it a 2040 profile.

I am trying to find a way I can do this using a joining plate so that I can easily assemble and disassemble it whenever required.

If someone can guide how? and where? I can buy the parts it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Weld them together, that's the best solution for metal profiles.

Comment: I found a plate which I can use to join them instead of welding, as it would mean a permanently joining the profiles.

Comment: Great. Good luck.